# dplyr mutate calling another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to mutate a dataframe by applying a function which calls out to another dataframe. I can acheive this in a few different ways, but would like to know how to do this 'properly'.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. I have a dataframe with some start times, and a second with some timed observations. I would like to return a dataframe with the start times, and the number of observations that occur within some window after the start time. e.g.

```
set.seed(1337)
df1 <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:3], start_time=1:3*10)
df2 <- data.frame(time=runif(100)*100)
lapply(df1$start_time, function(s) sum(df2$time>s & df2$time<(s+15)))
```

The best I've got so far with dplyr is the following (but this loses the identity variables):

```
df1 %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    do(count = filter(df2, time>.$start_time, time < (.$start_time + 15))) %>%
    mutate(n=nrow(count))
```

output:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 3 × 2
                  count     n
                 <list> <int>
1 <data.frame [17 × 1]>    17
2 <data.frame [18 × 1]>    18
3 <data.frame [10 × 1]>    10
```

I was expecting to be able to do this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:3], start_time=1:3*10)
df2 <- data.frame(time=runif(100)*100)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(count = nrow(filter(df2, time>start_time, time<(start_time+15))))
```

but this returns the error:

```
Error: comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

What is the dplyr way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another slightly different approach using `dplyr`:

```
result <- df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% 
                  summarise(count = length(which(df2$time > start_time &
                                                 df2$time < (start_time+15))))

print(result)
### A tibble: 3 x 2
##      id count
##  <fctr> <int>
##1      A    17
##2      B    18
##3      C    10
```

I believe you can use `length` and `which` to count the number of occurrences for which your condition is true for each `id` in `df1`. Then, group by `id` and use this to `summarise`.

---

If there are possibly more that one `start_time` per `id`, then you can use the same function but `rowwise` and with `mutate`:

```
result <- df1 %>% rowwise() %>% 
                  mutate(count = length(which(df2$time > start_time & 
                                              df2$time < (start_time+15))))
print(result)
##Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
##Groups: <by row>
##
### A tibble: 3 x 3
##      id start_time count
##  <fctr>      <dbl> <int>
##1      A         10    17
##2      B         20    18
##3      C         30    10
```

Comment: This also works if we use `mutate` in place of `summarise`, the benefit of this being that, if there are additional variables to the group by vars, they are not dropped

Comment: @kungfujam: Yes it does, but if there are more than one `start_time` per `id`, then we need to use the function `rowwise` instead of `group_by(id)`. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one option with `data.table` where we can use the `non-equi` joins

```
library(data.table)#1.9.7+
setDT(df1)[, start_timeNew := start_time + 15]
setDT(df2)[df1, .(id, .N), on = .(time > start_time, time < start_timeNew), 
           by = .EACHI][, c('id', 'N'), with = FALSE]
#   id  N
#1:  A 17
#2:  B 18
#3:  C 10
```

which gives the same count as in the OP's `base R` method

```
sapply(df1$start_time, function(s) sum(df2$time>s & df2$time<(s+15)))
#[1] 17 18 10
```

---

If we need the 'id' variable also as output in `dplyr`, we can modify the OP's code

```
df1 %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    do(data.frame(., count = filter(df2, time>.$start_time,
                                 time < (.$start_time + 15)))) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
#      id     n
#  <fctr> <int>
#1      A    17
#2      B    18
#3      C    10
```

Or another option is `map` from `purrr` with `dplyr`

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>% 
    split(.$id) %>% 
    map_df(~mutate(., N = sum(df2$time >start_time & df2$time < start_time + 15))) %>% 
    select(-start_time)
#   id  N
#1  A 17
#2  B 18
#3  C 10
```

Comment: @kungfujam  thanks, I updated the output based on that seed

Comment: The second solution (and third) does exactly what I want.